# What do you call leveraged real estate investors?

Tags: real-estate, terminology

Is there a specific term or name for people who try to make a living by leveraging real estate?

By that I mean those people who read get-rich-quick books and then borrow money to buy a property, rent it, and as soon as they have enough for a down payment they buy another property with borrowed money and so on and so on. What is that called?

Comment: Not sure if you are thinking of this answer to: [How do you invest in real estate without using money?](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/73757/14319)

Comment: Using leverage in investing and investing in real estate should be considered separately. The real estate crisis of 2008-2010 was in part caused by over-extended buyers and in part by the collapse of mortgage-backed securities (totally separate thing from actually owning real estate) which were in turn highly leveraged by some large hedge funds.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't consider it a get rich quick scheme, but this is a common approach for accumulating rentals. There are limits to how leveraged someone can become, because debt to income ratio is a loan criteria.

When I became a landlord I don't think people had put a name to it specifically, but recently BRRRR (Buy, Rehab, Rent, Refinance, Repeat) has become popular.

Others live in each new place while renovating before offering them for rent, not sure that approach has a popular name.